# When using the randint() function in python, I can't set the starting value at 1000?

Tags: python

Like it says in the description, anytime I try to set the initial value for randint to 1000, it breaks the function and kicks back an error.  I was wondering why this happens, and if there's any way to work around it.

```
a = input("Type a sentence: ")

print("\""+a+"\" is "+str(len(a))+" characters long")

tm.sleep(5)

clear()

x = 1

while x<1000:
    y = int(len(a)*3+150-12/2)
    chez = rd.randint(1000,y)
    tm.sleep(.0001)
    clean()
    x = x+1
    print(chez)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: How big is a typical y? If y < 1000, then `randint` will raise a `ValueError: empty range for randrange()`

Comment: @BatWannaBe You're right, I'm an idiot it didn't occur to me that the value of the string would be lower than the initial output

Comment: @Mureinik BatWannaBe had it,  my y values were less than 1000, which makes perfect sense in retrospect.

Comment: "set the initial value for randint to 1000" doesn't really make sense. What did you *expect* `y` to be, and why do you want a random number between 1000 and y? Did you perhaps want a number in [1000, 1000+y]? For the code as written, you would need a "sentence" with almost 300 characters before `y` would be greater than 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is that sometimes `y < 1000` and you just want a random integer between `y` and `1000` no matter which one is bigger, you can do this:

```
chez = rd.randint( *sorted([1000, y]) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error `ValueError: empty range for randrange()` because you're asking for random numbers in a range where the starting number is higher than the ending number. Switch the arguments and try it like this:

```
chez = rd.randint(y, 1000)
```